# Determine the Null space of $A$ vs Finding the basis for the Null Space of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I dont know if this is a stupid question or not but i wondering is they a difference between a question asking you to find the basis for the null space of A and determining the null space of A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming $A$ is a real $n\times n$ matrix.

Null space of $A$, say $N(A)$ is the set of $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax=0$. It is an easy exercise to verify that it a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now every vector space has a basis and the basis completely determines it.
As $N(A)$ is a vector space, it is completely specified by it's basis.

If you don't get a basis for $N(A)$, still $N(A)$  can be determined if you have  a spanning set for $N(A)$ (basis would be some subset of it).

Comment: what if A is a real m*n matrix

Comment: The thought process is the same.

Comment: oh ok i understand it cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well, the truth is, "determine" does not mean anything, in mathematics. What if, if $A$ is a $n\times n$ real matrix, and if you are asked to "determine" its null space, you give the answer: "it is $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ \vert \ Ax = 0\}$"? In this case, you would be right. But you might think it is not the good answer, and I'm betting that your teacher would agree.

In fact, "determine blablabla" is a pedagogical way of talking used by lazy teachers instead of "find an expression << hoketipoketi>> that I like as an answer and prove that blablabla = hoketipoketi".

As for vector subspaces, when you are asked to determine one (that is given by some equations, for example), the teacher probably means that he/she wants you to find a generating subset for it.

So, your question wasn't stupid at all; it only means that, as any other human being, you are not a telepath and therefore are not able to guess the correct question.